# Adjusting for mismeasured confounder

Tags: regression, causality, linear, confounding

Suppose I would like to determine the causal effect of $X$ on $Y$, where the relationship is confounded by $U$, but I measure $W$, which is a mismeasured proxy of $U$, as in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04945) paper. That is,

$$U \sim N(0,1)$$
$$W = \alpha_1 U + \sigma_1 \epsilon_1$$
$$X = \alpha_2 U + \sigma_2 \epsilon_2$$
$$Y = \beta X + \alpha_3 U + \sigma_3 \epsilon_3$$
$$\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3 \sim N(0,1)$$

Corresponding to this R code,

```
    N  <-  1E3
    e1  <-  rnorm(N); sig1  <-  1
    e2  <-  rnorm(N); sig2  <-  1
    e3  <-  rnorm(N); sig3  <-  1
    
    
    alpha1  <- 2; alpha2  <-  3; alpha3  <- 2
    beta_  <- -1.3
    U  <-  rnorm (N )
    W  <-  alpha1 * U + sig1 * e1
    X  <-  alpha2*U + sig2*e2
    Y  <-  beta_*X + alpha3 * U+ sig3*e3
```

If I regressing $Y$ onto $X$ and $W$, my result is quite biased.

```
lm ( Y~ X  + W)
```

This makes sense; as $\sigma_1$ increases, $W$ tells me less and less about $U$, and I hence cannot adjust for the confounding.

In this very simple, linear case, is there a closed formula for the bias in the estimate of $\beta$ as a function of $\sigma_1$?

Comment: I'm confused. Is $U$ measured or not? You cannot include $U$ on the RHS of a regression if it is unmeasured: you have no data for it! But if you do include it on the RHS because you do have data for it, then you're good: that adjusts for $U$ and the confounder is adjusted away.

Comment: $U$ is unmeasured, so I cannot include it in the RHS. I am asking about including $W$ in the RHS, as that is a proxy for $U$.

Comment: I don't have an analytical answer and I'm not sure that's helpful, but when I simulate this for varying $\sigma_1$ I get a curve somewhat proportional to $ 1 - e^{-x} $. Can't paste figures in a comment, so please see: [https://pasteboard.co/mBNMZLwjnqUz.png](https://pasteboard.co/mBNMZLwjnqUz.png)